# How to save a file in public folder using ReactJS and Docker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, file, multer

I'm using ReactJS and currently it works that way

1. The user uploads a file
2. I save it locally in a folder client/public/uploads with the package multer
3. I display it in my client page

So I decided to create a container on Docker, and everything works fine, but it seems like the files aren't saved to the folder, or that the client can't access it. Is it possible to save them there or is it necessary to use a cloud ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can map volume pointing to "client/public/uploads" to a docker volume. Refer: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: thanks, i'm looking into that! it seems to be the right thing ; i have to link the server to this folder.